# NoSQL aggregate command

Tags: mongodb, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I am new to NoSQL and trying to figure out how the aggregate works. It keeps erroring everytime I run my command.

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
    { $match: { loaction: "London"}},
    { $group: { _id: "$type_of_food"}}
    ]);
```

What are I doing wrong? This is using the Mongodb.

Identify the types of restaurant available in London, as well as their count; use the
aggregate( ) function

Comment: _"It keeps erroring everytime I run my command"_ - what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You need accumulator option to the group stage , example:

```
 db.restaurants.aggregate([
  {
   $match: {
   location: "London"
   }
  },
  {
   $group: {
    _id: "$type_of_food",
     count: {
     $sum: 1
    }
   }
  }
 ])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mGS5Wuzg64X)

Comment: Wow, I feel really silly. Thank you for the help R2D2. I was close.

Comment: ha ha , it hapens all time to me  ,it is just important to continue learning ;)